# How can I index a collection of records by one of their field?

Tags: collections, rust

I have a `Record` type, with a `get_key(&self) -> &str` method (borrowing the returned `str` from inside the record). Records may be mutable, but their key is guaranteed not to change.

I want to store a list of records in a collection, and be able to retrieve a record by its key. The first idea is to use a `HashMap<String, Record>`, but that looks like a waste of space (because the strings in the key position are copies of the record's keys).

I would rather have a `HashMap<&str, Record>`, but I can't provide a lifetime for the `&str` keys (since they are borrowed from *inside* the hashmap). This is the kind of self-reference that crates like [rental](https://crates.io/crates/rental) or [owning_ref](https://crates.io/crates/owning_ref) are designed to handle. However, none of them provide an out-of-the-box solution for this use-case.

I looked for a crate providing this kind of "indexed collection", but to no avail. Am I missing something? (I started hacking a solution of my own, but I'd rather not re-invent the wheel)

Comment: How about a `HashMap<Rc<String>, Record>`?

Comment: @Jmb This should be an answer.

Comment: Maybe you can use a `HashSet<WrapperRecord>`, having `WrapperRecord` contain a `Record` and implement `Hash` and `Borrow<str>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a container where the key itself is part of the value, you can use `HashSet` with a *newtype* to reimplement the required traits: `Hash`, `Borrow<str>`, `PartialEq` and `Eq`.

For example [(link to playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c752322f239b9a4a679bbf2841d86c27):

```
struct HRecord(Record);
impl Hash for HRecord {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        self.0.get_key().hash(state);
    }
}
impl PartialEq for HRecord {
    fn eq(&self, r: &HRecord) -> bool {
        self.0.get_key().eq(r.0.get_key())
    }
}
impl Eq for HRecord {}
impl Borrow<str> for HRecord {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &str {
        self.0.get_key()
    }
}
```

And now the `HashMap` just works:

```
let mut h = HashSet::new();
h.insert(HRecord(Record { ... }));
let obj = h.get("...").map(|h| &h.0);
```

Comment: That's indeed a nice way to implement it without a self-reference. I didn't think of implementing Borrow<str> so that I could use &str in h.get(...).

Comment: However, what I would like is a type abstracting this mechanism so that the user does not have to juggle btw Records and HRecords... Any crate providing that?

Comment: @Pierre-Antoine: Well, you can easily wrap a `HashSet<HRecord>` into a `RecordSet` and expose the proper `insert(&mut self, r: Record)` and `get(&self, &str) -> &Record` functions, and keep the `HRecord` private.

Comment: indeed, but then I would have to mirror all the usual container methods (iter, len, shrink_to_fit...), which is cumbersome, and could be factorized in to a generic type, hence my question.

Comment: that being said, I realized that, if I have control over the Record type (which is the case in my actual scenario), I don't need HRecord, I can simply implement Hash, Eq and Borrow<str> (thanks again for that tip) for Record itself, and then use a HashSet<Record>. E.g.: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a17a3af31afc43ebb1ecf594d997e55a

Comment: @Pierre-Antoine: That is up to you, of course. But implementing `Eq` for that may not be a good idea: being equal for indexing purposes does not necessarily mean being equal for everything. And a similar caveat for `Borrow<str>`.

Comment: You can instead implement `impl Deref<Target = Record> for HRecord` and `impl From Record for HRecord` That would minimize user inconvenience while keeping the `Record` unaltered.